# Getting layered PDF output from QGIS Map Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, pdf

I need to create layered PDF output from QGIS Map Composer so that one can turn the layers in PDF on and off. And I have no clue how to do it.

Is it possible at all and if so, how could I achieve it?